# Create a custom "Add Appointment" Button with Devextreme React Scheduler

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, scheduler

I´m looking all over internet for a way to implement a custom "Add Appointment" button on the Toolbar of the React Scheduler component from @devextreme. Creating an appointment with double click on the time view works really good, but I need to have an option to create from an external Button.

If anyone has implemented this and can point me in the right direction, I will be grateful.

as a reference, this are the package versions I'm using:

"@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^4.0.3",
"@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler": "^4.0.3",
"@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui": "^4.0.3",

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Parent component, this is where I wanted to create a custom button.
```

const SubjectAssignPage = () => {

```
//I made a function in the parent so that when the button is clicked, it will run the function I made in the child component that opens the appointment editor. I used a useRef to reference the child component.
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Call the function in the child component
    childComponentRef.current.openModal();
  };

  const childComponentRef = React.useRef();


    //Child component inside the parent component, where the scheduler lives. I removed the addButton Fab there.
     <div className={SubjectAssignCSS.tableWrapper}>
          <SchedulerFaculty ref={childComponentRef}/>
    </div>


    //The custom button

            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
              <Button
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={{ textTransform: "none" }}
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: "#007bff",
                  color: "white",
                  borderRadius: "0.5rem",
                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                  fontSize: isSmallScreen ? "0.6rem" : "0.9rem",
                  padding: "0rem",
                  padding: "0.9rem",
                  "&:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: "#0070e7", 
                  },
                }}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Assign
              </Button>
              
            </Stack>

-------------------
//Child Component, where the Scheduler lives and the function.

export default class SchedulerFaculty extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ....

//When custom button on the parent is clicked. It will call this and open the appointment editor.
  openModal(){
    this.setState({ editingFormVisible: true });
    this.onEditingAppointmentChange(undefined);
    this.onAddedAppointmentChange({
      startDate: new Date(currentDate).setHours(startDayHour),
      endDate: new Date(currentDate).setHours(startDayHour + 1),
    });
 
  }
```